# WPF ListView gets selected after item remove

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I am using a WPF ListView and after I remove an item from the ListView I get the following problem:

Before remove:
http://pokit.org/get/?fe754ed3ea76b2517851ef1bb8eeab5d.jpg

After:
http://pokit.org/get/?371c2590f5824f290f006f377de3064c.jpg

The ListView gets selected like when I navigate on it with the TAB key. How can I disable this behavior or may be disable this type of navigation on this item.

I remove the item programmatically:

listView.Items.Remove(item);

Answer (score 0):

When you add an Object into ListView. It creates a new Object with property. If it can be Focused. It will have TabStop property. You can use the TabStop or TabIndex to manipulate its behavior.

If it is still not working, make sure you enable the UseMnemonic to false. So all the Tab properties will not work.